# git checkout shell alias not working as expected

Tags: git, shell, zsh, alias

I'm using zsh and I added "gc" as an alias for "git checkout" as below in the .zshrc file.

`alias gc="git checkout "`

When I execute `git checkout dev`, it works fine. But `gc dev` doesn't work as expected. It shows:

> error: pathspec 'dev' did not match any file(s) known to git

May I have your advice on this issue? Thanks.

Note that I'm aware of Git Alias settings like `git config --global alias.co checkout`, but it still needs to type `git co`, which is 5 characters plus a whitespace. I'm wondering if it can be aliased as  `gc`.

Comment: Your alias works for me, no problem. Even `gc -b test` works.

Comment: Try the command `alias gc` to see the current setting for the alias. It looks like the `oh-my-zsh` alias `gc='git commit -v'` is overriding yours.

Comment: Just suggest add alias in the .gitconfig global config file.
Like:
`[alias]
 co = checkout
 st = status
 br = branch
 c = commit`

Then you can use git co,  git br, git st, git c etc.

Comment: the author edited the question later before I provided the suggestion. If he like to use linux original command.  I've no objection.  the command has no issue from my point.

Comment: @Sean "*…the author edited the question…*" [S]he didn't. The question currently is not edited even once (yet).

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @phd and @Gairfowl for investigating into this. They are absolutely right--my alias definition is overridden by the aliases of the git plugin of ohmyzsh, who has already done what I'm exactly trying to do. The full list of omz git aliases can be found [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git/).

The lesson I learned is that when an alias is not working as expected, firstly check if there are other aliases sharing the same name. In ZShell,  `compgen -a` (or `alias` with omz) will list all aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a function

```
gc() {
    git checkout "$1"
}
```

Comment: Aliases can handle parameters, in a limited way. With basic aliases, it acts like a string substitution of the leading part of what's typed.  For example, with `alias l='ls -al '`, the command `l aa bb` is expanded to `ls -al aa bb` and then executed.  Anything more complicated often requires a function.

Comment: @Gairfowl thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.